# Python ValueError: The number of columns in this dataset is different from the one used to fit this transformer (when using the fit() method)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, valueerror

I created a simple pipeline using sklearn. I created a data split using the following code:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
df.drop(['selling_price'], axis=1),
df['selling_price'],
test_size=0.1,
random_state=0)
```

I set my configuration (which variables to transform etc.) and called `pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)`. When I try to predict or score, e.g., using `pipeline.score(X_train, y_train)`, it returns a score. However, when I pass any other variation into the pipeline, e.g., `pipeline.score(X_test, y_test)` or even `pipeline.score(X_train.head(10), y_train.head(10))`, I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: The number of columns in this dataset is different from the one used to fit this transformer (when using the fit() method).
```

To clear out the following: the columns of both train and test splits are **exactly** the same, in terms of order, data type, etc. Also, the number of rows between `X_train` and `y_train`, as well as the number of rows between `X_test` and `y_test`, is consistent.

Full code (exluding imports):

```
# Load the dataset
df = pd.read_csv('car_prices.csv')

# Remove duplicates and NaN-values
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
df.dropna(inplace=True)

# Convert selling price
df['selling_price'] = df['selling_price']/100

# Split data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    df.drop(['selling_price'], axis=1),
    df['selling_price'],
    test_size=0.1,
    random_state=0
)

# Configuration
NAME_TO_BRAND = ['name']
NUMBER_OF_OWNERS = ['owner']
ENGINE_PROPERTIES = ['engine', 'max_power']

ONE_HOT_ENCODE = ['fuel', 'seller_type', 'transmission']

FEATURES = ['name', 'year', 'km_driven', 'fuel', 'transmission', 'owner', 'max_power', 'seats', 'seller_type', 'engine']

X_train = X_train[FEATURES]
X_test = X_test[FEATURES]

# Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline([
    
    # Transform variables
    ('transform_name_to_brand', pp.BrandTransformer(NAME_TO_BRAND)),
    ('transform_number_of_owners', pp.NumberOfOwnersTransformer(NUMBER_OF_OWNERS)),
    ('transform_engine_properties', pp.EnginePropertiesTransformer(ENGINE_PROPERTIES)),
    
    # One hot encode categorical variables
    ('one_hot_encode', OneHotEncoder(variables=ONE_HOT_ENCODE)),
    
    # Random Forest Regressor
    ('RFR', RandomForestRegressor(random_state=0)),
])

pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Evaluate model
car_pipeline.score(X_train, y_train) # returns 0.99
car_pipeline.score(X_test, y_test) # returns ValueError as specified above   
car_pipeline.score(X_train.head(1), y_train.head(1)) # returns ValueError as specified above
```

Comment: What version of sklearn is this?  `OneHotEncoder` doesn't have a parameter `variables` in any recent version, instead relying on `ColumnTransformer` to do column selection.  What is the namespace `pp`, and what do those transformers do?

Comment: Sorry, I used the function `OneHotEncoder` from `feature-engine`, which has the parameter `variables`. Also, `pp` is a self-written processing script that simply does some transformations to the data, like re-calculating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. In my pipeline, the categorical features are being one-hot encoded. In my training set, there were 42 unique categories, meaning that this will result in 42 columns when one-hot encoded. In my testing set, there were 27 unique categories, resulting in 27 columns when one-hot encoded. Thence, the ValueError was raised.

Comment: It would be great if you could share your solution.

Comment: The solution was deleting the categorical column because this is a dummy pipeline, so the features by itself did not really matter that much to me. In practice, I think there should be a validation step in the pipeline which checks the dataframe and reconstruct it if needed so that it is consistent with the original dataframe.

Comment: The `sklearn` `OneHotEncoder` would avoid this problem: the categories are learned at `fit` time, but at `transform` time only those learned categories are encoded; it doesn't "reset" the categories for the test set.  I'm surprised that `feature-engine` doesn't do that, and glancing at the source I don't think it should; maybe an older version of that package, or maybe your custom transformers are actually to blame?

Comment: I am using `sklearn` right now and this works better. I believe I was using the latest version of `feature-engine` but it did not seem to work out for me.